# Undefined method 'album_url' when deleting a photo and redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have user, album, and photo models set up as the following:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :albumusers
  has_many :albums, through: :albumusers, :foreign_key => :album_id

end
```

**album.rb**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true

    has_many :photos

    has_many :albumusers
    has_many :users, through: :albumusers, :foreign_key => :user_id
end
```

**photo.rb**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :album

    mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader

    before_create :default_title

    def default_title
        self.title ||= File.basename(image.filename, '.*').titleize if image
    end
end
```

**albumuser.rb**

```
class Albumuser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :album
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
    resources :albums do
        resources :photos
    end
end
```

**photo_controller.rb**

```
  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted photo"
    redirect_to @photo.album # ERROR is happening here
  end
```

When I try to delete a photo, I get error when trying to redirect back to the album show view.

Comment: can you add relevant code from the `Photo` model?

Comment: have you implemented a show view on your album controller?

Comment: Sorry, added code for Photo model.  Yes I have a album show view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in your routes:
your routes give you

```
    user_album_photos GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos(.:format)          photos#index
                      POST   /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos(.:format)          photos#create
 new_user_album_photo GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos/new(.:format)      photos#new
edit_user_album_photo GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos/:id/edit(.:format) photos#edit
     user_album_photo GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos/:id(.:format)      photos#show
                      PATCH  /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos/:id(.:format)      photos#update
                      PUT    /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos/:id(.:format)      photos#update
                      DELETE /users/:user_id/albums/:album_id/photos/:id(.:format)      photos#destroy
          user_albums GET    /users/:user_id/albums(.:format)                           albums#index
                      POST   /users/:user_id/albums(.:format)                           albums#create
       new_user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/new(.:format)                       albums#new
      edit_user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:id/edit(.:format)                  albums#edit
           user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)                       albums#show
                      PATCH  /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)                       albums#update
                      PUT    /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)                       albums#update
                      DELETE /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)                       albums#destroy
                users GET    /users(.:format)                                           users#index
                      POST   /users(.:format)                                           users#create
             new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                       users#new
            edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                  users#edit
                 user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                       users#show
                      PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                       users#update
                      PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                       users#update
                      DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                       users#destroy
```

As you can see, there is no route called `album`, only one called `user_album`.

You can either draw a direct route to albums so your
**routes.rb:**

```
resources :users do
    resources :albums do
        resources :photos
    end
end
resources :albums
```

normally, you could also redirect to `user_album` giving als well the user as the album:

```
redirect_to user_album_url(@photo.album.user,@photo.album)
```

but in your models, there is no single `user` for one `album`. So your routes do not reflect your model relationship. (Your routes imply then an `album` belongs to one `user`, your models say that `album` `has_and_belongs_to_many` `users`)